# Updating an adapter from a background thread

Tags: java, android

A few of my users (maybe 50) are getting crashes with the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread.

If I understand correctly, it's caused by calling `adapter.clear();` and `adapter.addAll(list);` in an AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` method, and I need to move it in the `onPostExecute()`.

The problem is I can't reproduce that error, so I can't be sure if it's fixed. Some similar questions on StackOverflow seem to indicate that simply moving the updating the adapter to the `onPostExecute()` method doesn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know how I can make this error happen every time on my device to make sure the fix worked? I don't get it why it would work in most cases but only sometimes cause a crash.

Comment: are you doing any inserts in your list at a certain point? If you are you can simulate that and see what happens

Comment: That exception is thrown in the `ListView` code in `layoutChildren()` when `mItemCount` is not zero and `mItemCount != mAdapter.getCount()`: [ListView.java](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.1.2_r1-robolectric-0/android/widget/ListView.java/?v=source)

Comment: The only thing I am doing with the adapter in `doInBackground()` is `adapter.clear();` and `adapter.addAll(list)`. I had that run hundreds of times on all my devices so far, not one crash.

Comment: Probably `layoutChildren()` is only being called when focus is lost and regained or the orientation is changed or something, which is why the exception doesn't always happen. Perhaps you can force it by calling `invalidate()` on the ListView? I would dig into the Android source and try to understand the conditions under which that code in `layoutChildren()` will be run.

Comment: But how do I make it happen on my devices? Why does it happen only occasionally when there is only one operation - adding stuff to the list. I did that hundreds of times and didn't get one crash. But my users are getting crashes.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks. I'll check out layoutChildren();

Comment: It could be a timing issue. For you users, the listview tries to layout some children after you change the items in the background thread but before you notify in the ui thread. To reproduce it you can try adding some sleep in doInBackground() after adding items to the adapter and play (scroll) with your listview

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you are forgetting to call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`.

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Get your data in background and update your adapter in `onPostExecute()` because you should never change a content of the adapter from background thread. Both `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` are executed on the UI thread.

Comment: I was calling that in `onPostExecute()` which happens right after. But I'm more interested in reproducing this error. For some reason it never happened for me, that's why it squeaked through.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce the issue, try sleeping after making changes to your adapter in doInBackground().

For example:

```
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    adapter.clear();
    try
    {
       Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){}
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
  }
```

Comment: Still doesn't crash the app.

Comment: @TimSim Does an exception get thrown at all?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call any UI things in doInBackground(..) method.
just call them in onPostExecute(..) as well as onPreExecute(..)

for example

```
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    adapter.clear();
  }
```

According to the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation, in the "The 4 steps" paragraph.

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>   passed to this step as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
                }
            });
```